# Machine Learning - Huge Only positive text dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, weka, text-classification

I have a dataset with thousand of sentences belonging to a subject. I would like to know what would be best to create a classifier that will predict a text as "True" or "False" depending on whether they talk about that subject or not.

I've been using solutions with **Weka** (basic classifiers) and **Tensorflow** (neural network approaches).

I use string to word vector to preprocess the data.

Since there are no negative samples, I deal with a single class. I've tried one-class classifier (*libSVM* in Weka) but the number of false positives is so high I cannot use it.

I also tried adding negative samples but when the text to predict does not fall in the negative space, the classifiers I've tried (NB, CNN,...) tend to predict it as a false positive. I guess it's because of the sheer amount of positive samples

I'm open to discard ML as the tool to predict the new incoming data if necessary

Thanks for any help

Comment: Before answer your question I need more information:
1. Are you using Doc2Vec, Word2Vec or some other algorithm to represent a text as a vector?
2. How you created your negative samples?  Did you check that they are negative or they are generated randomly? What the number of negative samples?

Comment: 1. I'm using word2vec
2. There are no negative samples in the original formulation of the problem. I added some to try to build a classifier with skewed data. These negative samples, when I used them, were from a completely different subject. Thanks, Stepan!

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I think that the key reason of inefficiency of classification ML algorithms in your case is in big difference of samples quantity for each class in a training dataset. From my experience, the best accuracy can be reached with equal quantity of samples for each class. Could you create 1000 negative samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that that adding of at least 100 negative samples for author’s dataset with 1000 positive samples is acceptable for the author of the question, since I have no answer for my question about it to the author yet

Since this case with detecting of specific topic is looks like particular case of topics classification I would recommend using classification approach with the two simple classes 1 class – your topic and another – all other topics for beginning

I succeeded with the same approach for face recognition task – at the beginning I built model with one output neuron with high level of output for face detection and low if no face detected

Nevertheless such approach gave me too low accuracy – less than 80%
But when I tried using 2 output neurons – 1 class for face presence on image and another if no face detected on the image, then it gave me more than 90% accuracy for MLP, even without using of CNN

The key point here is using of SoftMax function for the output layer. It gives significant increase of accuracy. From my experience, it increased accuracy of the MNIST dataset even for MLP from 92% up to 97% for the same model

About dataset. Majority of classification algorithms with a trainer, at least from my experience are more efficient with equal quantity of samples for each class in a training data set. In fact, if I have for 1 class less than 10% of average quantity for other classes it makes model almost useless for the detection of this class. So if you have 1000 samples for your topic, then I suggest creating 1000 samples with as many different topics as possible

Alternatively, if you don’t want to create a such big set of negative samples for your dataset, you can create a smaller set of negative samples for your dataset and use batch training with a size of batch = 2x your negative sample quantity. In order to do so, split your positive samples in n chunks with the size of each chunk ~ negative samples quantity and when train your NN by N batches for each iteration of training process with chunk[i] of positive samples and all your negative samples for each batch. Just be aware, that lower accuracy will be the price for this trade-off

Also, you could consider creation of more generic detector of topics – figure out all possible topics which can present in texts which your model should analyze, for example – 10 topics and create a training dataset with 1000 samples per each topic. It also can give higher accuracy
One more point about the dataset. The best practice is to train your model only with part of a dataset, for example – 80% and use the rest 20% for cross-validation. This cross-validation of unknown previously data for model will give you a good estimation of your model accuracy in real life, not for the training data set and allows to avoid overfitting issues

About building of model. I like doing it by "from simple to complex" approach. So I would suggest starting from simple MLP with SoftMax output and dataset with 1000 positive and 1000 negative samples. After reaching 80%-90% accuracy you can consider using CNN for your model, and also I would suggest increasing training dataset quantity, because deep learning algorithms are more efficient with bigger dataset

Answer (score 1):

I have eventually added data for the negative class and build a Multilineal Naive Bayes classifier which is doing the job as expected.

(the size of the data added is around one million samples :) )

Comment: So, the key points in my answer were correct about increasing number of negative samples and using of classifier? 

I wonder about more details about your data set. What’s the exact numbers of positive and negative samples?

BTW, to increase accuracy I would recommend try xgboost or neural networks I suggested as an example in my answer

Comment: It's a naive bayes classifier that is giving the best results. Not surprising. I did add samples as to the negative ones to be more or less the same number as the positive and that made the difference (as said).

Comment: I wonder about a cross validation accuracy of the naive bayes classifier you mentioned. Also, I think that comparison with other ML algorithms can be interesting not only to me

I heard that a naive bayes classifier can be efficient for text classification, but I'm not sure is it really more efficient than, for example, xgboost

I will highly appreciate if you could give us some numbers about the cross validation accuracy of algorithms you been checked

Answer (score 0):

For text data you can use Spy EM.

The basic idea is to combine your positive set with a whole bunch of random samples, some of which you hold out. You initially treat all the random documents as the negative class, and train a classifier with your positive samples and these negative samples.

Now some of those random samples will actually be positive, and you can conservatively relabel any documents that are scored higher than the lowest scoring held out true positive samples.

Then you iterate this process until it stablizes.